# iFrame with Mobile mode

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe, mobile, desktop

My website http://asmgx.com is to create a short URLs for longer links

the site itself is auto adjust to mobile or desktop mode
I can view the website perfictlly in mobile mode (dimensions)

but when i view a link on it say http://asmgx.com/rjk it display in desktop mode.

by that i mean when I assign the iFrame to a link, the link remains in desktop mode

[image]

what shall i do to make iFrame display the src link based on the device it views.

my code is

.aspx file

```
<iframe id="frmURL" runat="server" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

.aspx.cs file

```
                    this.frmURL.Attributes.Add("src", sURL);
                    this.frmURL.Attributes.Add("style", "overflow: hidden; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: " + iFrameTop.ToString() + "px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">` to end up with a more responsive site,
instead of iFrame